# R counting duplicate items that occur in multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr

```
#Create a sample data frame:

set.seed(1)

Data <- data.frame(Vendor_ID = sample(1:10000), Bank_Account_ID = sample(1:10000))
```

Hi everyone. I have a dataframe that is a collection of Vendor IDs and a bank account number for each vendor. I'm trying to find a way to count the number of duplicate bank accounts that occur in more than one vendor_ID.

I can do a count of bank accounts that occur within the same vendor using dplyr and group_by and count, but I can't figure out a way to count duplicates among multiple vendor_IDs.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does `Data %>% group_by(Bank_Account_ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(Vendor_ID) > 1)` do what you need?

Comment: that seems to produce a tibble but I am trying to add a new variable column with the count of repeating bank accounts in each row of the original data frame, if possible.

Comment: Ah, I see.  How about `Data = Data %>% group_by(Bank_Account_ID) %>% mutate(Num_Vendors) = n_distinct(Vendor_ID))`?

Comment: Gives me a strange error: 

Error in list2(...) : object 'Vendor_ID' not found

Comment: There is an extra `)` in `mutate` for the code above.  Although the sample data does not appear to have any duplicates.

Comment: @manotheshark is right; that should have been `Data = Data %>% group_by(Bank_Account_ID) %>% mutate(Num_Vendors = n_distinct(Vendor_ID))`.

Answer (score 0):

Since that A.S.K.'s comment output seems to be accepted:

```
library(dplyr)
DataDplyr = Data %>% 
  group_by(Bank_Account_ID) %>% 
  mutate(Num_Vendors = n_distinct(Vendor_ID))
```

You can also use data.table to get the same output:

```
library(data.table)
DataDatatable = as.data.table(Data)
DataDatatable[,Num_Vendors:=uniqueN(Vendor_ID),.(Bank_Account_ID)]
```

Testing whether the 2 outputs are equal:

```
all_equal(DataDplyr,DataDatatable)
#[1] TRUE
```